# Does the existence of Grothendieck Universe contradict with axiom of choice?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I am a beginner for set theory and I find something interesting:

Let $ U $ be a Grothendieck universe, then $ (U, \subseteq) $ is a partially ordered set. For every nonempty chain $ \mathcal{K} $ on it, $ \bigcup\mathcal{K} $ is an upper bound of $ \mathcal{ K } $. Thus by Hausdorff's maximal principle, which is equivalent to axiom of choice, the partially ordered set $ (U,\subseteq) $ has a maximal element $ M $. Put $ M^+=M\cup\{M\} $, since $ U $ is a Grothendieck universe, so $ M^+ $ is in $ U $. But by axiom of regularity, we have $ M \subsetneq M^+ $, and this contradicts with that $ M $ is a maximal element.

Does this means that the existence of Grothendieck universe contradicts with axiom of choice? Has this ever been considered before?

Comment: @SamMoore But it would give that U is in U, if U is a maximal element of U...

Comment: Does the existence of $\omega$ contradict the Axiom of Choice? If $n<\omega$, then $\bigcup n\in\omega$ as well. No, it's just the case that the chain that is maximal, in this case $\omega$, is not an element of $\omega$.

Comment: @SamMoore That's not the issue.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Oh, thank you! I realize that I am wrong here. I forget that grothendieck universe is closed under union that can be indexed by a set that contained in the universe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with this proof is that you don't necessarily have that $\bigcup \mathcal{K}$ is in $U$ again. Universes aren't closed under *all* unions, just unions indexed by elements in $U$.

For example, if we consider $V_\omega$ (the collection of [hereditarily finite sets](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/hereditarily+finite+set)) as a countable Grothendieck universe and let $0 = \emptyset$ and $n+1 = n \cup \{n\}$, then the collection $\{0, 1, 2, 3 \dots\}$ is a chain in $V_\omega$, but the union is an infinite set, hence not in $V_\omega$.

Comment: Yeah, I realize that I have made a mistake, I forget that the chain K may fail to be indexed by a set that contained in the universe. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6):

It is **not** true that the poset $(U,\subseteq)$ has a maximal element. This is because a chain can stretch all the way through $U$; take, for example, $\mathcal{K}=U\cap\mathsf{Ord}$ as the set of ordinals in $U$.

All "short" chains through $(U,\subseteq)$ - that is, all chains which themselves are elements of the universe $U$ - have upper bounds, but that's not enough to get Zorn to apply (we can't even fix this by "working inside $U$" since $(U,\subseteq)$ is itself not a set in $U$).

---

It may help to replace $U$ with the set $\mathsf{HF}$ of **hereditarily finite** sets. This set (also called $V_\omega$ or $L_\omega$) is easily checked to satisfy all the properties of universes that are relevant for your idea, as well as the axiom of choice regardless of whether choice holds in $V$ itself. This is a much more transparent setting for these sorts of "overreach" ideas.

Comment: Thank you very much! I realize that Grothendieck universe is just closed under union that can be indexed by a set that contained in the universe, not just closed under arbitrary union.